# Authlogic login on different browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm using authlogic 3.3.0 and rails 3.2.
Every time user logs in, its session is stored in cookie (including persistence_token).
If the same user logs in from different browser (i.e. mobile), its persistence token in DB is overwritten and hence is invalid for the desktop browser. How to keep one session on different browsers?

Comment: Without getting any answer I've made a 'quick*dirty' fix: I've just copied the whole module and changed function  def reset_persistence_token
            self.persistence_token = Authlogic::Random.hex_token if self.persistence_token.blank?
          end

Comment: Do you simply want multiple active logins, or actual shared sessions? The former is much easier than the latter.

Comment: Multiple active logins